# What does "E-Z" mean?

Tags: american-english, abbreviations

Is it an abbreviation or is it used instead "A-Z"?

I have seen it being used multiple places:

- E-Z cook oven
- E-Z Hiscores

Comment: Not to mention the IRS form 1040EZ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_1040#Short_forms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means 'easy'. The two sounds for those letters in the (American) English alphabet sound out the word *easy*.

Answer (score 4):

It means *easy* as this is pronounced similar to *E Z* in American English.

Answer (score 0):

"E-Z" is a lazy way to write the word *easy*. This is in American English because the letter *z* is pronounced as "zee" in America. This does not apply in British English because the letter z is pronounced as "zed".